# Cross ( mobile ) platform image transitions

Tags: livecode

I'm writing a game that asks the user to click on an image, which then reveals a different image. I'd like to make the transition between the images look like a playing card being turned over on both Android and IOS.

I've done a bit of research, but it all seems to indicate that the "curl" visual effect will do what I want, but is only available on IOS ( I can't test this as I don't have access to a MAC at the moment. )

Is there a cross platform way of doing this "turning a playing card over" sort of transition?

Answer (score 0):

You might scale the (front) image control vertically until it is only 1 line and then scale the second (backside) image from 1 vertical line to its original size.

Only very few visual effects are cross platform. One of them is the reveal up/down/left/right effect. You might use this effect to display a neutral, e.g. gray or blue picture after hiding the front side image and before showing the back side image. Something like this:

```
lock screen for visual effect
hide img "front"
show img "intermediary"
unlock screen with visual effect reveal left fast
lock screen for visual effect
hide img "intermediary"
show img "back"
unlock screen with visual effect reveal right fast
```

I know it isn't ideal, but if you want it to be cross platform, you need to find a workaround. Why don't you check for the platform and write a different conditional routine for each platform?

Answer (score 0):

I think the effect you want is flip and yes it's only available on iOS at the moment. There are a couple of iOS visual effects that push the image into a UIView and animate that with native methods. This blog post indicates it would be possible to implement something similar on android but it would need to be in the engine: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-scale-animation-to-simulate-a-3d-flip/